# Steps to merge and push code into master from dev

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I want to understand how to push code into master from dev.

For this I tried:

- I go to dev branch and pulled latest code from dev using : git pull origin dev
- I committed new change to dev but not pushed yet
- I go to master branch and fetch latest code from master using : git pull origin master
- I go to dev branch and to merge into master I used : git merge master
- And after that I push the code into master using git push origin master

Is this the right step to merge code from dev into master? Or is there something that I am missing?

As I am very new to git I don't want to mess up so I created this question.

If anyone needs any information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

One step i wrong:

```
1. [OK] I go to dev branch and pulled latest code from dev using : git pull origin dev
2. [OK] I committed new change to dev but not pushed yet
3. [OK] I go to master branch and fetch latest code from master using : git pull origin master
4. [WRONG] I go to dev branch and to merge into master I used : git merge master
5. [Partially OK] And after that I push the code into master using git push origin master
```

The steps 4 and 5 must be:

```sh
git checkout master
git merge dev
git push

git checkout dev
git push
```

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding `git push --all`: if you want to push both `dev` and `master` to `origin`, use `git push origin dev master`, for instance. It's not that `--all` is *wrong*, it's just often *too powerful* here. It's also a bit confusing that `git fetch`'s `--all` means *all remotes* while `git push`'s `--all` means *all branches*, hence my advice to avoid `--all` in general.

Comment: Thank you so much for you valuable input @AntonioPetricca

Comment: It can actually be useful to first merge master into dev to deal with possible conflicts there. Then once that merge is complete, merging dev into master will also succeed (provided nobody else has pushed changes to master in the meantime). I consider that to be proper "branch hygiene".